# How can I change the slider value within the while loop in each case in LabVIEW?

Tags: timer, slide, labview, led

There are six LEDs that light up one after the other. I want to control the speed of the flashes with a slider. Unfortunately, after reaching station A, the value of the slider actually changes. I want if I change the slider while running, I can immediately notice the change in the flash of the LEDs. Anyone have any idea how this could be solved?

[Block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF7MN.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code,

1. plz make another while loop.
2. And then, put your slide(timer) in the new while loop.
3. And then, connect the slide to Labview timer by using local variable.

This is an example block diagram.

[image]

The corresponding front panel is this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it really works!

Answer (score 1):

Solution could me more elegant.

[image]

Comment: I just started using labview recently and I don't know what the array on the left does and when I connect it to the while loop what does that green arrow mean?

Comment: @DavisDeepwater The green "arrows" signify inputs and outputs of a shift register. The array on the left initializes this shift register. What goes into the shift register on the right will be on the left next time the loop iterates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more detailed explanation to the code of KKS:
You need a second while loop to change the time of your slider immediately. If you keep one while loop only, the new value of the slider will be active only in the next iteration.
You need to put your slider in the second while loop and this loop needs to run faster than your while loop which contains your LEDs.
In order to connect the value of the slider in the fast while loop with your slow while loop, you can use local variables.